# Text watcher in android works once only

Tags: android

I have written a key listener on a edit text in android.
Following is my code:

```
textview.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter"
        // button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // Perform action on Enter key press
            if (textview.getText().toString().length() == 15) {
                textvalue = textview.getText().toString();
                textview.setText(replacecardformat());
                textview.clearFocus();
                Log.e(""TAG, "Executed");
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

However the log statement is executed only once.Is some problem in my return statement.

Comment: `Log.e(""TAG,"Executed");` - is this really intentional?

Comment: This isn't a `TextWatcher`, this is an `OnKeyListener`. The documentation for `OnKeyListener` says _"This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener."_ Do you have a hardware keyboard?

Comment: @DavidWasser,Sorry David you are right edited my question.I want to display a Toast message when user enters a 15 digit number and presses enter or goes to next field(edittext).

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

- if you need listener on each text change use `view.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)`. Text Watcher has three methods: one fired before, one after, and one on text change. I suppose that this is what you are looking for. More details and [tutorial you can find here](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/action-on-edittext-change-listener/)
- is your `textview` an `TextView` or `EditText`? I am asking since only `EditText` can receive keyboard input. however `TextView` can have such listener too. Because its text can also change ([see documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)).